# My Access Point isn't working, could I get some help?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, access-point

I went through a tutorial on thepi.io. However, my AP isn't showing up or not working.  I ran the:

```
    sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

then it came back as:

```
    failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (operation no supported)

    rfkill: WLAN soft blocked

    wlan0: could not connect to kernel driver 

    Using interface...

    Failed to set beacon parameters

    wlan0: could not connect to kernal driver

    Interface initialization failed 

    wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED

    wlan0: AP-DISABLED 

    wlan0: Unable to setup interface.

    wlan0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
    wlan0: AP-DISABLED 

    hostapd_free_hapd_date: Interface wlan0 wasn't started 

    nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

I apologize for the formatting errors if there are any, I could really use some help.

Comment: Your question popped up again. Does my answer helped you? If so please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish your question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

The first message `failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (operation no supported)` doesn't matter. Monitor mode isn't supported by the on-board WiFi device. The kernel only tells you this.

But the second message is important:

```
rfkill: WLAN soft blocked
```

All other messages are follow up messages. I don't know why, because by default the device isn't soft blocked. You have to unblock it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

Show status with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo rfkill list
```

If `Wireless LAN` is `Soft blocked: no` then **hostapd** should start.

If you don't have `rfkill` installed, just install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install rfkill
```